# GD image resize not working on production server (Amazon EC2 Ubuntu)

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, gd

I have two dev environment setup

1. Test - PHP Version 7.0.33-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1  **+**  **GD** headers Version 2.2.5 (as per phpinfo)
2. Production - PHP Version 7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 **+**  **GD** headers Version 2.1.1 (as per phpinfo)

on **Amazon EC2 Ubuntu** in which i am trying to use **image resizing** with **codeigniter** image manipulation class with this code.

```
$resizeConfig['image_library']  = 'gd2';
$resizeConfig['source_image']       = $imageName;
$resizeConfig['new_image']      = $imageName;
$resizeConfig['width']              = 320;
$resizeConfig['height']         = 215;
$resizeConfig['maintain_ratio']    = FALSE;
$resizeConfig['quality']            = '100%';
$this->load->library('image_lib');  
$this->image_lib->initialize($resizeConfig);
```

both the servers are showing `GD` **installed** and **enabled** if i check on `PHPINFO()`

The problem is **TEST** Environment works fine with the code and resizing images on the fly. However, **PROD** server not working with image resizing with the same code. Install `GD` on `PROD` with this command

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd`

Please help me out what i am missing over here. Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: do you get any error message ?

Comment: RESTART the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was not enough for production server. since i am working with codeigniter. I had to add following line.

`$this->image_lib->resize();`

after

`$this->image_lib->initialize($resizeConfig);`

But i still wonder how the same code was working with testing server without that additional line.